# R newbie question regarding column, variable, and table

Tags: r

I am a SAS user and just started to use R.

I wanted to calculate the tax bracket, I know it's a classic problem but having trouble understanding/grasping the gist of using R.

I want to generate a sequence from 1 to 1m, then based on the sequence value I then calculate the tax paid. I know in SAS it'll simply be tax = income * rate on top with if-else clauses, how can I achieve this using R?

I saw a basic function:

```
income_tax <- function(income) {
  # Calculate income tax liability based on income
  #
  # Returns the amount of income tax owed
  
  if (income > 0 & income <= 9875) {
    tax = 987.5
  } else if (income > 9875 & income <= 40125) {
    tax = 9875 + (income - 9875) * .12
  } else if (income > 40125 & income <= 85525) {
    tax = 4617.5 + (income - 40125) * 0.22
  } else if (income > 85525 & income <= 163300) {
    tax = 14605.5 + (income - 85525) * .34
  } else if (income > 163300 & income <= 207350) {
    tax = 323271.5 + (income - 163300) * .32
  } else if (income > 307350 & income <= 518400) {
    tax = 47367.5 + (income - 307350) * .35
  } else if (income > 518400) {
    tax = 156235 + (income - 518400) * .37
  } 
  return (tax)
}
```

But this function only outputs a single value? I cannot operate on the whole sequence of the income variable as to how it operates in SAS. How can I better grasp the idea behind all these, any text recommended? Many thanks.

Comment: do you want the output to be a new column in your dataset

Answer (score 0):

We can `Vectorize` the function

```
df1$newColumn <- Vectorize(income_tax)(df1$income)
```